# Como dividir números grandes sem o python abreviar ele?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sempre que eu tento fazer cálculos no python com números grandes, ele acaba abreviando o resultado.

Por exemplo:

```
a = 8682372684397235357614080000
b = 86400
c = a/b

print(c)
1.0049042458793097e+23 \\resultado
```

Eu gostaria de imprimir o numero inteiro.

Comment: `print(f'{c:f}')` veja [Minilinguagem de especificação de formato](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: print(round(c))

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar o número por inteiro, você deve usar uma “string” formatada, ou seja, para determinar o modo como ele sera printado na tela:

O tipo "float" pode ser formatado destas formas:

- :.0f # sem zeros a esquerda
- :.2f # com dois zeros

Obs: pode se colocar mais do que 2 apenas.

Neste caso

```
a = 8682372684397235357614080000
b = 86400

c = a/b # divisão normal

print(f"{c:.0f}") # :.0f sem zeros a esquerda
```

Resultado:
100490424587930965114880